# phpMyAdmin setting LIMIT 1 to a specific table automatically

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm having a weird issue when doing a SELECT in phpMyAdmin without a LIMIT it adds a "LIMIT 1" (and not the default LIMIT 25 which is added at the other tables)

For example when I press the browse tab this is the query that phpMyAdmin displays: `` SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY date LIMIT 1 ``

Comment: Please give a step-by-step, preferably tried on https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE.

Comment: Step by step of what? I'm using phpMyAdmin on tons of projects and databses and I have one table that whenever I do a query and I'm not specifying a LIMIT it adds LIMIT 1, for example when I press the browse tab this is the query that PMA displays SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY date LIMIT 1

Comment: A few questions. Happens just on this table? Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Yes, only one table, Version 4.6.6deb5

Comment: Maybe you have a query bookmark whose name is the same as the table that shows this behavior and which contains the LIMIT clause. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/bookmarks.html?highlight=bookmark#browsing-a-table-using-a-bookmark

Comment: No, no bookmarks at all

Comment: If you point the mouse on the header of the date column when browsing you'll see a hint to remove the sorting on this column. What happens if you remove this sorting?

Comment: Wow!! I did remove it and the limit is fixed now, Can you please explain to me how this effected the limit in the first place? 

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure; if you click on the same header to sort, does the limit come back?

Comment: No. It doesn't come back

Comment: If it has a LIMIT 1 you have to edit the query to increase that before the header hint which shows the sort option will appear. If there is only one row visible the tooltip doesn't appear and the column header is not listening to events. Read the keyboard modifiers very carefully! Thanks! This one had me panicking for most of a day, and riled up for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Point the mouse at the header of the sort column when browsing. You'll see a hint to remove the sorting on this column. - Marc Delisle Sep 25 '19 at 14:41

If the query has a LIMIT 1 you have to edit the query to increase that LIMIT. Otherwise the header hint mentioned above which shows the sort option will not appear. If there is only one row visible the column header object is not listening to events so you can't sort and you don't see the hint.

Read the keyboard modifiers very carefully! Removing the sorting on the column should fix this. Credit should go to Marc Delisle for this answer.